# Generate a data-time format from 2 separated strings

Tags: php, datetime

I need to compare date/time that I get from MySQL with a format like: `2013-05-17 15:07:29`

From another database, I have data and time separated and in the notation: `130998 081836`

I have concatenated the two strings to get only one and I'm trying to convert it to my desired format using:

```
$dateTimeNmea = $array[9]." ".$array[1];          //  130998 081836
$dateTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $dateTimeNmea);   //  1970-01-02 13:23:18
```

So "it works" on the format but the values are wrong. It could be `1998-09-13 08:18:36`

Where is my fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`130998 081836` is not a format for a date that the `date` function can understand.

For starters the `date()` function expects the second param to be a timestamp (read docs for it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php))

Then you would need to parse the string into a useable date format via `date_parse_from_format` and finally into a timestamp

Something like

```
$string = '130998 081836';
$date = date_parse_from_format('dmY His', $string);

$dateString = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(vsprintf('%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s', $date)));

var_dump($dateString); // var dump just for output/test
```

The `strtotime(vsprintf('%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s', $date)` formats your parsed date into a timestamp which can then be used in `date` methods second param to get exactly the format you need.

Answer (score 1):

It has format `siH dmy`. Try `date_parse_from_format('siH dmy', $string)` to get it in array.